# Как сделать путь директории без слеша в конце?

Tags: php, api, path

У меня сейчас есть директория api, в ней лежит папка auth, а в ней файл index.php. Получается путь к path получается такой "localhost/api/auth/".
А как мне сделать вот такой путь "localhost/api/auth" ? Нужно какой-то файл создать в папке api?

Comment: Это нужно для чего?

Comment: .htaccess? (5 символов)